# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.contacts' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `contacts` limit 1)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I cloned a new project from GitHub, when the cloning is finished, I went to the project folder and run `composer install` first it was giving the below error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `contacts` limit 1)
```

Then I run `composer update` & `cp .env.example .env` & changed the `.env` file and created my database. Now that I run `composer update` and `php artisan key:generate`, it will give the below error and it is not working.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database_name.contacts' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `contacts` limit 1)
```

**Contacts Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contacts extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table="contacts";

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'youtube_link',
        'facebook_link',
        'twitter_link',
        'instagram_link',
        'phone_number',
        'email_address',
        'location_link',
    ];
}
```

[image: Composer Install Image]

[image: When Composer Install Finished]

[image: The Error That Gives Now]

Comment: Have you executed migrations if any ?

Comment: @SatyandraShakya migration is also not working, I manually created the table that it gives error then it gives the same error for another table.

Comment: oh ok, this might be due to some of the migrations are not available. Suppose if, the migration of contact table is not in your code and there might be another migration for alter contact table, then alter migration will create this problem. Or there could be ordering of the migrations.

Comment: @SatyandraShakya All the migration files are available, and also the orders of all migrations are correct.

Comment: You can execute migration one-by-one.

Comment: @Hedayatullah Sarwary please share your model here

Comment: This is a new cloned project, even the `php artisan key:generate` is not generate, and also `composer update` is also not working, then the `php artisan migrate:fresh` is also not working.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Is this a Composer problem, or a Laravel problem? Why not use `composer install --no-scripts`  if any post-install-command throws an error?

Comment: @NicoHaase `composer install --no-scripts` is working, every time we need to add **--no-scripts**, because without that it is not working.

Comment: @NicoHaase Also after that when I run 'php artisan key:generate', it will give this error: **SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using passw
ord: NO) (SQL: select * from `contacts` limit 1)**

Comment: Sounds like you are using the wrong database credentials. This does not look related to Composer after all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your laravel service providers , you may define the Contacts Model in one of your providers ,
because you face this error during composer installation .
first comment or remove that Model then run `composer install`.

I faced the same issue before

Comment: Thanks, I have created a ContactServiceProvider, inside that I have called two or three models. I have commented those calls to models. now it is working.

Comment: thanks to all. dametoon garm. hamin bood. i started the new legacy project that it has codes in service provider i temporary comment and problem here and solved. now i can find another solution for this. thank you